# PLSQL : To show data from multiple tables efficiently on page loading

Tags: plsql

I am using data from multiple tables (6 tables) from multiple schemas to show a grid on the launch of an application. Due to many outer joins it is taking very long to load the initial page. How can i increase the efficiency of my program.

Comment: Performance tuning is a big subject. What part do you need help with? Can you check the execution plan of the query? Are the cardinality estimates about right or way off?

Comment: Which database do you use? Which kind of an application is it? What tool do you use? Do you apply *filters* later, once the initial record set is being displayed? You know - show me everything, and then I'll filter out what I don't need. If so, use a condition that is *false* at the beginning so that nothing is displayed initially. Apart from that, try to rewrite a query, going step by step, optimizing each of them. If *multiple schemas* also mean *different databases*, then yes - things might be going rather slow. Anyway: do provide some more info.

Comment: i use oracle database. The front end is a .NET application. My PL/SQL procedure is called from .NET code to display the data on initial launch of the application.Yes, once the initial record set is displayed, i am applying filters to go further to search for something, update something.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to optimize,

1. you could start paginating the query results. i.e show only few results in the page at a time and click on page number to see the other results.
2. Optimize your query. There are options like Query plan that can give you an idea about the performance of the query. Also preferably use SQL queries and avoid using Procedures

Comment: I am already using paginating option. Showing only 100 results in a page.